# How to manipulate timeouts in Handler

Tags: go, gorilla

I have set read and write timeouts to 5 seconds. But I have handler responsible to add data from excel which takes more than 5 seconds to complete the request.
So what I want to do is change or increase the read/write timeout by **X** amount of time if the request is not completed within 5 seconds.
I have implemented TimeoutHandler provided by net/http package to cancel the request if it is not completed within specified time.
What are the ways to do this? How can I manipulate the timeout?

Comment: If the part that takes more than 5 seconds actually is *sending* the data (as opposed to any processing that happens before you even begin to send the first byte), that's a known shortcoming of the Go STL. Instead of trying to change the deadline after the fact, you should look out for middlewares that implement true timeout behavior.